# Global symbol requires package name error in perl script

Tags: perl

**Error**:*"Global symbol "$ipn" requires explicit package name at perl.pl line 66. Global symbol "$sizen" requires explicit package name at perl.pl line 76. Execution of perl.pl aborted due to compilation errors."*

```
$iaddr = inet_aton("$ip") or die "Cannot resolve hostname $ipn";
$endtime = time() + ($time ? $time : 1000000);
socket(flood, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 17);

print "Flooding $ip " . ($port ? $port : "random") . " port with " . 
($size ? "$size-byte" : "random size") . " packets" . ($time ? " for $time seconds" : "") . "n";
print "Interpacket delay $delay msecn" if $delay;
print "total IP bandwidth $bw kbpsn" if $bw;
print "Break with Ctrl-Cn" unless $time;

die "Invalid packet size requested: $sizen" if $size && ($size < 64 || $size > 1500);
```

Comment: the code you posted doesn't have `$ipn` or `$sizen`. make sure you posted the right error or the right code. And please ask a question.

Answer (score 9):

You have [strict](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?strict) turned on (which is always a good idea).  It's complaining about these calls:

```
die "Cannot resolve hostname $ipn";
die "Invalid packet size requested: $sizen"
```

because you haven't declared variables named `$ipn` or `$sizen`.  Did you mean:

```
die "Cannot resolve hostname $ip\n";
die "Invalid packet size requested: $size\n"
```

If so, then `strict` was doing its job, and catching your mistake.  You have some other strings that end in `...n"` that probably should have been `...\n"`, but since those aren't variable references, `strict` can't tell there's a problem.

Comment: I'm guessing he got the code from some web forum that ruined the original code, in this case, by deleting backslashes. It's not unlikely that the same thing happened in other places where it didn't result in a syntax error (or at least, a violation of `strict`).